# Changing values within a very large collection (10,000)

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I am importing a very large file (2-3 GB of text) into a collection, 10,000 at a time. I need to apply certain business rules to the values contained within the collection. What would be the best way to do it?

The initial idea was to create a `List<>` of a custom class, but it is becoing very heavy. Further, I am not sure how to efficiently change the values within the list. For example, for all items in the list, If the property x is "abc", I need to change it to "xyz".

Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to deal with 10,000 at a time? If you can reduce that requirement the gain should be obvious, though I'm guessing that isn't trivial (or you'd already be doing so).

Comment: any reason not to use a complete stream here? i.e. no batches - just buffered input/output and a single item at a time?

Comment: If the maximum size of the list is constant, use a constructor that accepts a capacity argument (e.g., `new List<CustomType>(10000)`).  This will reduce the number of allocations on the large object heap (LOH).  If the list's size might not remain constant, then use a linked list, which doesn't allocate any arrays, and therefore does not allocate anything on the LOH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `List<T>` should be absolutely fine. If you only ever need to iterate, you *might* want to consider using a `LinkedList<T>`, but I'd expect IO to dwarf everything else here.

As for your changing:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item.Property == "abc")
    {
        item.Property = "xyz";
    }
}
```

... is about as simple to read as it gets, IMO. You *could* use `List<T>.ForEach` if you really wanted, or LINQ - but I generally dislike changing values within a query result, if it would change the result. For example:

```
// I dislike doing this, though it would work:
foreach (var item in list.Where(x => x.Property == "abc"))
{
    item.Property = "xyz";
}
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: It feels too close to modifying the iterator (which would break). For example, if you start messing around with an `XDocument` in a query which works over it, it will break - in this case it *will* work, but it's too close for comfort.

Answer (score 3):

Why not apply the business rules when you get the values from the stream before you put the items in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a in memory database, this would help you carry out fetch, update operations efficiently. The resulting code would be cleaner to maintain, as you would be using declarative logic rather than imperative logic. Please do this if you this is a project at your workplace.